# Stop exit function from not displaying rest of the page

Tags: php, function, die

If the users rank is not above 1, the *exit function* is used

The problem is, if the *exit function* is used, any code after it will not be displayed on the page

Let's pretend that my rank is not above 1, here is what happens:

```
<?php
if($memberinfo3['rank'] < 1)
{
echo "<br><br>Your accounts rank is not sufficient to access this page.";
exit;
}
echo "Passed!";
?>

<?php include 'template/sidebar.php'; ?> <---- NOT DISPLAYED

<?php include 'template/footer.php'; ?> <---- NOT DISPLAYED
```

I want to stop the *exit function* from not displaying the code on the rest of the page. I have looked up documentation on exit, die, and return, and have had no luck on fixing my problem

Comment: That's what the exit function does! If you don't want it to terminate the script, don't use it... you can always put the `echo 'Passed!'` in an `else`

Comment: `if($memberinfo3['rank'] < 1)
{
echo "<br><br>Your accounts rank is not sufficient to access this page.";
}else{
echo "Passed!";}`

Comment: @MarkBaker using an else completely slipped my mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an architectural problem. The `exit` function is supposed to function like this. A better solution would be to do something like this:

```
<?php
    if($memberinfo3['rank'] < 1) {
        require 'guest.php';
    } else {
        require 'logged-in.php';
    }
?>
```

Try that instead.

Another option is to redirect them somewhere else. That can be a whole lot cleaner than showing an error message to the user as well.

```
<?php
    if($memberinfo3['rank'] < 1) {
        header('Location: /homepage_location.php');
    }
?>
```

But remember, if you use the `header` function you have to execute the statement prior to the output buffer being flushed (i.e., before `echo`, `print`, or other output statements).